# VB.net Windows Service not installing

Tags: vb.net, windows-services

I have created a Windows Service in VB.net for building xML from a database. I need to install it in my machine. I have followed all the steps as shown in
http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx/kb/816169

When I right click on setup project and click install it opens the installation wizard and after hitting the next buttons it promptly says that the Service is installed successfully.

When I go to Services I don't see the service. I refreshed the list and rebooted my machine n times.

Please help.

Comment: Are there any entries in your Application log (in Event Viewer) that might shed light on what might be going on?

Comment: Just a small note. Link is outdated. I appreciate question is old however links can help to understand when someone is having a similar issue and provides context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you use InstallUtil.exe found in C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727 (assuming .net 2.0) to install a .net service on your own machine.

Also look at this question - [install-a-service-from-command-line-vb-express-2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958891/install-a-service-from-command-line-vb-express-2008)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you updated the ServiceName property in your class file?

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
   components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
   this.ServiceName = "Service1";
}
```

This is what will show up in the Services List (not what you might have named the program).

Answer (score 0):

please check this http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251192.
using sc.exe you can install service with different parameters.

Comment: why - 1 ? i used sc.exe for service installation and maintenance.